Do I need to protect ICs with transils?
In datasheets (for ex. this or this) I can see that ICs have an integrated protection against voltage transients. So should I add additional protection as TVS diodes?
My reasoning is no, as open-case microcontrollers like Arduino and Raspberry Pi don't use them. It's also unheard of to add other protections that are integrated in ICs like clamp diodes.
But I'm unsure. What I'm working with is a controller for a robotic arm moved with stepper motors. I'm certain that somebody in a sweater on a dry winter day is going to stick their electrically charged fingers into the datalines that go to the robot's tool and it's limit switches.

It depends on the intended environment of the product and if you only wish to use them just as anti ESD or if you need them to remove stronger spikes yet.
In industrial/automotive products, you expect spikes and noise to be present on the machine, often originating from fast toggling of inductive loads like motors and valves, and you expect such spikes to carry lots of energy. So you always add one (or even several) TVS on the supply. 1600W 10/1000 μs "peak pulse" rating is some industry standard there, meaning more rugged than the average TVS. Overkill for commerical applications, too little still for some military EMC standards - it depends.
Additionally, any I/O which is dragged out around the machine should also ideally be protected with TVS. Particularly things like motor or valve drivers. These may or may not need as beefy protection, or perhaps none at all - it's on case to case basis.
For protection against ESD, modern IC have such diodes built-in, although not necessarily of the highest ESD rating (8kV contact 15kV air). But your application might not need the highest ESD rating either - again, it depends on your specification.

My reasoning is no, as open-case microcontrollers like Arduino and Raspberry Pi don't use them.

Those are toy boards designed by/for hobbyists. So that's like saying that live ponies don't need food because the My Little Pony plastic toy you bought at the toy store doesn't need it :)

Sometimes yes, sometimes no.
Your assumption is poor, however: understand that those boards are sold as development kits, to be used by trained technicians, or installed in equipment that does provide such protection (whether by prevention or added limiting devices).
Perhaps this, too, is a poor assumption.  It might be assumed by the manufacturers as a cost-cutting measure.  The ICs might even survive commercial test levels: the commercial ESD test is a one-off trial, and long-term survival, or failure statistics, is not part of it.  (Devices can be partially damaged, and fail functionally at a later date, sometimes exacerbated by exposure to operating voltage, or high temperatures; or fixed in turn.  ESD failures can be intermittent(!).
Or I'm the one making the bad assumption: one can check the CE compliance declaration to see what standards, if any, they've tested to, and how (hopefully..).  Maybe they've abused the parts but gotten away with it, maybe they haven't tested at all; maybe they tested in an oversimplified manner (no wire length or ground return, reducing the "reaction mass" and thus energy absorbed by the board).
As for test levels, that's intuitively important.  Both linked devices are rated 2kV HBM.  That's like cars bumping into each other in a parking lot, maybe it leaves a dent, maybe it's fine.  It's not something you want to be standing (bodily) in the middle of, but within the body of a car it's probably fine.  Typically commercial test levels are 4kV contact, 8kV air discharge: like cars on city streets colliding, damage is done but it's likely survivable, might even be able to drive away from it.  Levels go up to 15/8kV, sometimes even more, for more stringent products, industrial, etc.: like cars crashing on the highway.
It's not at all impossible for a chip to survive such levels, even with such meager ratings.  Not every chip will fail immediately, and not every chip will fail latently.  Enough will fail, that the manufacturer has seen fit to set the test level as given.  (To continue stretching the automotive analogy: people have survived highway crashes without seatbelts, getting ejected onto the roadside and falling to a rest with mere minor abrasions.  That it's possible, doesn't mean it's something you want to count on...)
As for protection, it's not quite as simple as throwing TVS everywhere.  That does help, but understand what's happening at the pin.
The pin has some internal resistance, thus developing a voltage in response to the ESD current.  ESD currents are huge, if brief: 20A easily, at full test levels in a proper fixtured setup.  It only lasts perhaps 50ns, but in that time, plenty of energy is available to vaporize microscopic structures (a chip's ESD diodes might be mere ~µm across).  Across a few ohms internal resistance, that develops 10s of V.
If we attach an external device that has, say, fractional ohms incremental resistance, it might clamp at 8V, 20V, something like that -- or more if it has significant inductance, including stray due to wiring -- and thus absorbs some of the current that would otherwise have to flow into the IC.
We can reduce current into the IC further by placing a series resistor between TVS and IC.  The TVS might spike to 30V, and then we can add enough resistance to make this 30V pulse look like less than an HBM pulse at the IC pin: a few A peak, or perhaps we want an even tighter limit like falling under the CMOS latchup level, and 100mA would be desirable.  In that case, ((30V) - (3.3 + 0.5V)) / (100mA) = 272Ω.
But notice that we've added resistance, and capacitance, to the circuit.  Clamp style TVS diodes can get quite low indeed in capacitance, but we're still adding something, and we have the RC filter of the series resistor plus pin input capacitance, or the pin is output and the resistor limits drive strength to the subsequent trace / bus / cable.  This would be problematic if we're driving a stiff load (10s mA, say), or at high speed (a 20Mbit SPI bus >1m long, likely wouldn't meet signal quality).
So there are many considerations, and many solutions we can employ.
As for the robotic arm, don't lose sight of other possibilities.  If a part of the arm isn't firmly grounded (and I mean at RF: we're talking nanosecond rise times here, literally a wavefront expanding at the speed of light), the cable running within it is effectively floating, and couples that transient voltage, some fraction of it anyway, directly into the cable within (or along it).
Induced energy is significant for ESD: enough such that, one of the standard tests, is simply placing a metal plate beside the EUT (equipment under test), and zapping that from a few sides, and in a few orientations.  This mimics real-world scenarios like ESD strikes to a nearby filing cabinet, or metal desk, or desktop PC, etc., and the EMP from these events can be just as dangerous as direct hits to IO pins.
The stepper motors are not without concern, either: particularly for high-efficiency and microstepping drivers, their switching outputs can have quite rapid rise/fall time, on the order of 10ns perhaps, and this makes quite a din into the 10s and low 100s of MHz: moreover, levels are such that coupling into nearby signal lines can easily corrupt data on them (e.g. 10s of V to the motor, single V coupled into lines, and a 3.3V LVCMOS signal only has about 1V of noise immunity in the best of times).  EMI or full PWM filtering may be a desirable addition, or placing the drivers directly at the motors and extending a shield and ground from motor housing to the board, thus minimizing antenna length plus stray inductance.

" like Arduino and Raspberry Pi" /--/ "understand that those boards are sold as development kits, to be used by trained technicians"  Err, no. They are rather sold as hobbyist kits, to be used by untrained hobbyists for recreational purposes. Not to be placed anywhere near real products.

@Lundin More generally, dev/eval boards -- which are often functionally or schematically identical to those boards in particular, so, take your pick which combination of assumptions applies.

Either way, neither hobby boards nor eval boards should be "installed in equipment that does provide such protection".

That seems a very superstitious statement -- or I'm missing your context here.

I don't know how common it is for development boards, but TI have documents such as Evaluation Board/Kit Important Notice which contains This evaluation board/kit does not fall within the scope of the European Union directives regarding electromagnetic compatibility, restricted substances (RoHS), recycling (WEEE), FCC, CE or UL, and therefore may not meet the technical requirements of these directives or other related directives.
